# Foremost (data recovery) does not find deleted files (or any files)

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to recover a deleted .jpg file. I know it was deleted as I did it specifically. However, when I run 'foremost', nothing happens and the program just runs and never ends. Am I not doing something obvious here?

```
foremost -t jpg -i /dev/nvme0n1p5 -v

Foremost version 1.5.7 by Jesse Kornblum, Kris Kendall, and Nick Mikus
Audit File

Foremost started at Wed Mar  2 12:40:47 2022
Invocation: foremost -t jpg -i /dev/nvme0n1p5 -v 
Output directory: /home/blobfish/output
Configuration file: /etc/foremost.conf
Processing: stdin
|------------------------------------------------------------------
File: stdin
Start: Wed Mar  2 12:40:47 2022
Length: Unknown
 
Num  Name (bs=512)         Size  File Offset     Comment
```

Comment: More details please. Where was the file when it was deleted on a local path or on another machine or what? It may not affect this question but it is a good idea to always include the version of Ubuntu in the question.

Comment: you haven't indicated your ubuntu version, please update your question accordingly. In the meantime, does the man page for foremost provide any additional help?

Comment: How long ago was that file deleted? NVMe drives do not retain deleted information for very long, making recovery quite challenging as hours turn to days ...

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is 20.04. The file was deleted a few minutes before I ran the program in the ~/home/username directory. I have read the man page plus a number of tutorials so I am fairly sure my syntax is correct which is why I was confused that the program just ran. It does not stop running; perhaps that is the problem?